# Test if Postman response body Json is an array or object

Tags: javascript, postman

I have a API that I'm testing and I'm expecting `responseBody` to be a Json object (starts with "{"). However it could be that due to an unexpected event the response could be returned as an array (starts with "[").

How can I determine the type (array or object) of `responseBody` using Postman tests?

So far the best I have is:
When expecting an object (not an array)

```
var bodyJson = pm.response.json();
tests["Response should not be an array"] = !(bodyJson instanceof Array);
```

Comment: In some cases with API responses, it may place the JSON object into an array on its own.

Comment: You can check it using different tool, as JMeter with Response assertion

Answer (score 8):

You could just use:

```
pm.test('is an Array', () => pm.expect(pm.response.json()).to.be.an('array').but.not.an('object'))
```

Taken from [ChaiJS](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_a) - which is built-in to the native *Postman* application.

Answer (score 4):

For example you have the following json

```
{
  "testA": [1, 2],
  "testB": {"a": "b"}
}
```

you can use `Array.isArray()`

```
var bodyJson = pm.response.json();
tests["Response should not be an array"] = !Array.isArray(bodyJson['testA']); // false
//tests["Response should not be an array"] = !Array.isArray(bodyJson['testB']);  // true
```

Or

```
var bodyJson = pm.response.json();
pm.test("is Array Test", function() {
    var notArray = !Array.isArray(bodyJson.testA) // false
    // var notArray = !Array.isArray(bodyJson.testB) // true
    pm.expect(notArray).to.eql(true);;
});
```